# Mocha:How to bail only failed describe() in nested describe()?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

My test structure is as follows

```
describe('Test Suite'){
     describe('First Test Case'){
        it('1st step'){};
        it('2nd step'){};
        it('3rd step'){};
    }
     describe('Second Test Case'){
        it('1st step'){};
        it('2nd step'){};
        it('3rd step'){};
    }
}
```

I want to use **--bail** such that if inside First Test Case any it() fails then that describe() should be bailed.But the Second Test Case should run.

I am getting the expected result by using:

```
describe('Test Suite'){
     this.bail(false)
     describe('First Test Case'){
        this.bail(true);
        it('1st step'){};
        it('2nd step'){};
        it('3rd step'){};
    }
     describe('Second Test Case'){
        this.bail(true);
        it('1st step'){};
        it('2nd step'){};
        it('3rd step'){};
    }
}
```

**Is there any other way to do it without explicitly assigning bail to true in each describe()?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround, maybe it will help.

You can set up your condition not by file but my function name or test name.

In setup file:

```
const FAILED_TESTS = {};
// Skip test if first test from folder failed
beforeEach(function() {
  if (FAILED_TESTS[this.currentTest.file]) {
    this.skip();
  }
});

afterEach(function() {
  if (this.currentTest.state === "failed") {
    FAILED_TESTS[this.currentTest.file] = true;
  }
});
```